# ERROR AND/OR CORRUPTED GEM

Tags: rspec, rubygems

I'm receiving an error when using the gem install rspec command, I'm new at programming and it seems like whatever has gone wrong is over my head. Any advice or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]

RVM -v
rvm 1.21.20 (stable)

The problem: Whether I type gem install rspec, gem -v, which gem, gem list here is the message:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/config_file.rb:221:in `read': Is a directory - /Users/JTee/.gemrc (Errno::EISDIR)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/config_file.rb:221:in`load_file'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/config_file.rb:168:in `initialize'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:384:in`new'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:384:in `configuration'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:634:in`path'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:68:in `installed_spec_directories'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:58:in`from_installed_gems'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:881:in `source_index'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/gem_path_searcher.rb:81:in`init_gemspecs'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/gem_path_searcher.rb:13:in `initialize'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:839:in`new'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:839:in `searcher'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:838:in`synchronize'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:838:in `searcher'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:478:in`find_files'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1103
    from /usr/bin/gem:8:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/gem:8

Answer (score 0):

Try removing /Users/JTee/.gemrc.  It is supposed to be a file but on your computer it is a directory.